# wayland and remote desktop

Tags: remote, remote-desktop, remote-management, wayland

apparently Fedora 25, even if in alpha state (not for long, beta comins soon) is doing extremely well with Wayland enable by defaut. I wonder if there's any graphical/easy_to_setup solution out there for remote desktop management (under another linux machine) out there that will work with Wayland? Or is it too early? Any help appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 3):

**Updated answer:**

There has been recent work to [bring remote desktop capabilities to GNOME under Wayland](https://ctrl.blog/entry/wayland-gnome-remote-desktop). It looks like the old screen sharing server, Vino, will be replaced by a new GNOME Remote Desktop service. At least for GNOME under Wayland, remote desktop over VNC will be a thing in the not too distant future.

**Old answer:**

It’s not supported yet. The official answer is “use X if you need remote desktop access.” You can login under X rather than Wayland by clicking on the settings gear on the login screen. There doesn’t seem to be much work on this from GNOME as of yet, with little evidence other than [a single initiative page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Initiatives/Wayland/Remoting).

Comment: Any update for GNOME or KDE or general WayLand?

Answer (score 1):

[Written](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTM0MDg) by Michael Larabel in Wayland on 2 April 2013 at 04:12 AM EDT:

> RDP Back-End Merged For Wayland's Weston Now having undergone six code
>   revisions, the Weston Remote Desktop Protocol back-end has been
>   merged.
>
> This RDP back-end to Weston waits for RDP clients to connect and then
>   sends frame-updates to these clients. Each RDP client has its own seat
>   -- thereby being multi-seat friendly in Weston -- and frame updates can be done with surfaces or the RemoteFX codec. FreeRDP is in
>   compliant with most of Microsoft's RDP 7.1 protocol.

Most distros have RDP-client software installed out-of-the-box or in their repositories so connecting should not be a problem.

Comment: This isn’t relevant unless you’re using Weston, which is nothing more than a reference implementation of Wayland. Fedora 25 Workstation uses GNOME’s Wayland compositor.

Comment: Yes and having a reference implementation in Weston brings it closer to having it implemented in others - such as in Gnome compositor - as you state in your own updated answer.